# Single word for "enclosed in parenthesis"

Tags: single-word-requests

> **X**<sup>(1)</sup>
>
> The number *enclosed in parenthesis* in the superscript signifies the first slice of the tensor **X**

This is my sentence. I want to replace the italicized phrase with a single word that demonstrates that the number is inside the parenthesis. I'd write the sentence as it is but for some reason, the repetition of "in" is annoying me.

I faintly remember a word that started with en- that'd do the trick but I can't recall now. Is there a word that means "enclosed in parenthesis"?

Comment: You could also say, “The number enclosed by parenthesis...”

Comment: The 'bracketed' number ...

Comment: I think parenthesized is the best word. You should add that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to it as a **parenthetical** :)

> *[parenthetical](https://www.bing.com/search?q=define%20parenthetical%20&pc=MOZI&form=MOZLBR)* [ˌperənˈTHedək(ə)l] adj - relating to or inserted as a parenthesis

So, for your example:

> X(1)
>
> The *parenthetical* value(/number/figure) signifies the first slice of the tensor X

Although in this case, "the superscript" would also describe the same thing.

Comment: Note that "parenthetic" shows in the dictionary as being able to be used in exactly the same way.  Both are adjective that mean the same.  Just noting that the "al" is not required at the end if OP prefers the sound of it without the "al".

Answer (score 0):

- The number *(in parentheses)* in the superscript etc etc
- The *reference number* in the superscript etc etc
- The *(reference)* in the superscript etc etc

Answer (score 0):

While using an adjective is fine, I personally prefer a verb for this. So, I would say:

> The **parenthesized** number signifies the first slice of the tensor X.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [parenthesize](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parenthesized):

> : to make a parenthesis of : enclose within parentheses

---

Note that the word you may have been thinking of was *enclosed*. However, it can't be used on it's own in this particular context.

Also, when you indicate the number that's been parenthesized, you are also indicating the number that's in superscript, so there is no reason to additionally include that part of the description. Even if you don't replace your original use of *enclosed in parentheses*, you can still drop *in the superscript* and the reference will be understood.